# Openpyxl border of adjacent cells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working on a project where I have to detect all the cells with borders, but I'm facing a problem, I don't know if this is intentional, but why does openpyxl takes the border of two adjacent cells as distinct, for example:

If the cell B2 has a bottom border then the cell B3 should have a top border, but when I try with this:

```
if ws['B2'].border.bottom.style is not None:
    print("B2")
if ws['B3'].border.top.style is not None:
    print("B3")
```

It only prints `B2`

As I said, I don't know if this is intentional or a bug, because I tried the same with C# excel interop and both statements printed the value, meaning the border exist in both cells

So, does adjacent cells in excel can have different borders, is it a bug in openpyxl or I'm making a mistake?

Comment: I believe adjacent cells can, indeed, have different borders, even if the visual effect is the same. If I open Excel, create a bottom border on B2, create a top border on B3, and clear the borders on B2, the top border from B3 still appears (visually indistinguishable from a bottom border from B2).

Comment: I tried the same, but when I remove the bottom border of B2, the top border of B3 disappears as well, I have Excel 2016.

Comment: Admittedly, I tried this on LibreOffice Calc 6.0.7.3. But I believe the same logic still applies, at least when working with openpyxl anyways.